# Need guidance in joining SQL queries

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

The column - PCT_COL_IND is a BOOLEAN Column.

```
SELECT ID,
MAX(CASE WHEN PCT_COL LIKE '%no-response%%' OR PCT_COL LIKE '%ind-not-found%' 
    OR PCT_COL LIKE '%search_res_not_found%' OR PCT_COL LIKE '%empty%' THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END) AS PCT_COL_IND   
FROM table1 A
LEFT JOIN table2 B
ON B.p_id = A.p_id
WHERE date = '2022-02-02'
GROUP BY ID
  )


ID        PCT_COL_IND
519181    FALSE
694562    FALSE 
694892    FALSE
```

When I run the above query separately, I'm getting values for PCT_COL_IND as FALSE.

When I join the above query with two other queries, I'm getting values for PCT_COL_IND as NULL.
I'm trying to insert the source records to target table using Stored Procedure in Snowflake.

But when I join the above query along with two other queries, I'm getting NULL values for most of the records
for PCT_COL_IND column. I should not display the NULL results.

Can someone suggest me with any logic?

I have mentioned the entire query below:

```
    SELECT distinct
        a1.id,
        a1.date,
        a1.begin_time,
        a1.Pno,
        b1.PCT_COL_TXT,
        b1.PCT_COL_IND,
        CASE WHEN final.id is  NULL then 'I' ELSE 'U' END as DML_Type
        FROM(
        SELECT 
distinct id,
min(date) over (partition by id order by date) AS date ,
first_value(timestamp_col) over (partition by id order by cast(pno as int)  nulls last) as begin_time,
first_value(pg_col) over (partition by id order by cast(pno as int)  nulls last) as Pno,
row_number() over(partition by id order by date) as RNK
FROM table1
WHERE  date = '2021-11-02'
QUALIFY RNK=1
)a1
left join 
(

SELECT id,
    CASE 
       WHEN PCT_COL  LIKE '%no-response% then true
       WHEN PCT_COL  LIKE '%no-response%' then true
       WHEN PCT_COL  LIKE  '%no-response% then true
       WHEN PCT_COL  LIKE '%no-response%' THEN 'TRUE' 
       ELSE 'FALSE' END AS PCT_COL_IND, 
  
  
        CASE WHEN listagg(DISTINCT PCT_COL ,',')WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY PCT_COL )='' THEN NULL
ELSE REPLACE(lower(LISTAGG(DISTINCT PCT_COL , ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY PCT_COL )),'+','') END AS PCT_COL_TXT

FROM table1 B
LEFT JOIN table2
ON B.s_id = A.s_id
WHERE date = '2021-11-02'
GROUP BY 1,2
 )b1 
ON b1.id=a1.id
LEFT JOIN
(select distinct 
id ,
cr_date,
begin_time,
Pno,
fin_pno,
PCT_COL_TXT,
PCT_COL_IND,
row_number() over(partition by id order by cr_date DESC) as RNK
FROM table4
QUALIFY RNK=1
)final on a1.id = final.id
WHERE (final.id is NULL)
or                                                            
(
    nvl(a1.id,'0') <> nvl(final.id,'0' )
    OR nvl(a1.date,'0')<> nvl(final.cr_date,'0') 
    OR nvl( a1.Pno,'NA') <> nvl(final.Pno,'NA')
    OR nvl( a1.fin_pno,'NA') <> nvl(final.fin_pno,'NA')
    OR nvl( b1.PCT_COL_TXT,'NA') <> nvl(final.PCT_COL_TXT,'NA')
    OR nvl( b1.PCT_COL_IND,'0') <> nvl(final.PCT_COL_IND,'0')
  )
```

I have tried the logic but still getting NULL values.

Comment: Can you check by doing the following 1) Check the value of PCT_COL  when doing a Left outer join 2) Check the value of PCT_COL  with out the join and  see where it is True, dose it have any value which matches the conditions in the CASE statement.

Comment: Without using JOIN I'm getting TRUE AND FALSE values. But when I did a LEFT JOIN, I'm getting most of the values as NULL. We are joining one table with the other using the ID column. Say Table A, B and C. Table B is having the PCT_COL column. ID value in table A is not matching with ID value in table B. But it is matching with Table C.

Comment: It could be you are doing a LEFT join that is why you are getting a NULL, but need more information, Can you please give us the DDL , some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: Thanks Himanshu. I'll update shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, that CASE statement can be written in different ways. And as you current have it, it is rather hard to read in my opinion.

```
SELECT
    column1 as PCT_COL
    ,CASE WHEN PCT_COL LIKE '%no-response%%' OR PCT_COL LIKE '%ind-not-found%' 
        OR PCT_COL LIKE '%search_res_not_found%' OR PCT_COL LIKE '%empty%' THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END as logic_1
    ,CASE 
       WHEN PCT_COL LIKE '%no-response%%' then true
       WHEN PCT_COL LIKE '%ind-not-found%' then true
       WHEN PCT_COL LIKE '%search_res_not_found%' then true
       WHEN PCT_COL LIKE '%empty%' THEN 'TRUE' 
       ELSE 'FALSE' 
     END as logic_2
   ,PCT_COL LIKE ANY ('%no-response%%', '%ind-not-found%', '%search_res_not_found%', '%empty%') as logic_3
   ,NVL(PCT_COL LIKE ANY ('%no-response%%', '%ind-not-found%', '%search_res_not_found%', '%empty%'), FALSE) as logic_4
FROM VALUES 
    ('not like any of these'),
    ('BLAHBLAHBLAH ind-not-found BLAH BLAH'),
    (null);
```

the second CASE `logic_2` while taking more space if, you have to use a case is flows better to my eye. But we can do better and just use [LIKE ANY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/like_any.html) as shown in logic_3 but that has a down side of if the input is `NULL` the result is NULL, so a NVL cleans that up, as seen in `logic_4`

| PCT_COL | LOGIC_1 | LOGIC_2 | LOGIC_3 | LOGIC_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'not like any of these' | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 'BLAHBLAHBLAH ind-not-found' BLAH BLAH | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
| NULL | FALSE | FALSE | NULL | FALSE |

so that helps point at one of the possible sources of you NULL, related to you left join, if you have only NULL's for `PCT_COL` your current code will not give you a NULL response, so this is not you problem.

The next thing you code does is it uses MAX to aggregates these TEXT strings. As an aside using TEXT strings can be very inefficient, but for now let ignore that. And look at how MAX behaves over different input.

```
SELECT column1 as ID, MAX(column2)
FROM VALUES
    (1, 'TRUE'), (1, 'TRUE'),
    (2, 'TRUE'), (2, 'FALSE'),
    (3, 'TRUE'), (3, null),
    (4, 'FALSE'), (4, 'FALSE'),
    (5, 'FALSE'), (5, null),
    (6, null), (6, null)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

| ID | MAX(COLUMN2) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | TRUE |
| 2 | TRUE |
| 3 | TRUE |
| 4 | FALSE |
| 5 | FALSE |
| 6 | NULL |

So the only case where MAX give the result you don't want (NULL) is when all the input given to is are NULLs. Otherwise 'TRUE' or 'FALSE' strings are better.

So this points to you LEFT JOIN is not matching, for some ID's and thus producing only NULL values.

So you then need to decide "do you want those NULL values for reason X" at which point you need to mask this, I would suggest wrapping you code in `NVL(<expression>,FALSE)`  to find this edge case.

But also at the same time, given you are getting the results of LEFT JOIN that you seem to not want. perhaps you don't want the LEFT JOIN. But given this is also example code, you might be needing those LEFT JOINs for "some other reason".

So I would use:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    NVL(MAX(PCT_COL LIKE ANY ('%no-response%', '%ind-not-found%', '%search_res_not_found%', '%empty%')),false) AS PCT_COL_IND   
FROM table1 A
LEFT JOIN table2 B
    ON B.p_id = A.p_id
WHERE date = '2022-02-02'
GROUP BY ID
```

BUT that does not have the OUTPUT of `PCT_COL_IND` as an uppercase string, of which if you really need, I would flip over to IFF and be explicit about what you are doing:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    MAX(IFF(PCT_COL LIKE ANY ('%no-response%', '%ind-not-found%', '%search_res_not_found%', '%empty%'),'TRUE','FALSE')) AS PCT_COL_IND   
FROM table1 A
LEFT JOIN table2 B
    ON B.p_id = A.p_id
WHERE date = '2022-02-02'
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: I just added the entire query. Could you please guide me on this?

Comment: @Jenifer I love that the code always has that `WHERE date = '2021-11-02'` in it...

Comment: Yes I tried running the script for November 11, 2021. I may have given the wrong date initially. Sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

So to review your SQL it can be cut down to this:

```
SELECT 
    a1.id
    ,b1.pct_col_ind
    ,CASE WHEN final.id is NULL then 'I' ELSE 'U' END as DML_Type
FROM (
    SELECT 
        column1 as id
    FROM VALUES 
        (1),
        (2),
        (3)
) AS a1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM VALUES 
        (1, true),
        (2, true),
        (3, false)
    v(id, PCT_COL_IND)
) AS b1 ON a1.id = b1.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM VALUES 
        --(1, true),
        (2, true),
        (3, false)
    v(id, PCT_COL_IND)
) AS final ON a1.id = final.id
WHERE final.id is NULL
    OR nvl(a1.id,'0') <> nvl(final.id,'0' )
    OR nvl( b1.PCT_COL_IND,'0') <> nvl(final.PCT_COL_IND,'0')
;
```

We only get output under 3 conditions, where the final does not match the a1 row (this can be triggered by missing id some id's in final. So lets have 3 ID's in a1 that are not in final. and the in B1 have one of those be true, and one be false and one not exist there.

Now the next reason we get output is `a1.id != final.id` but given we join on them being equal, we will only be here if final.id is null, thus we already triggered the first OR or if there are nulls in the ID's of A1 at which point both a1.id and final.id are null, and thus converted to `'0'` thus are equal, thus it's a pointless clause and not the problem we are looking for.

So the third reason to get rows into the output. is if `nvl( b1.PCT_COL_IND,'0') <> nvl(final.PCT_COL_IND,'0')`. again if the right hand side is null we are already in and if both sides are null we are not going in. Thus this code is saying if I had a value value, and the left join on B1 failed then NVL will make b1.PCT_COL_IND -> '0'

all the talking transforms the code into:

```
SELECT 
    a1.id
    ,b1.pct_col_ind
    ,CASE WHEN final.id is NULL then 'I' ELSE 'U' END as DML_Type
FROM (
    SELECT 
        column1 as id
    FROM VALUES 
        (1),
        (2),
        (3),
        (4),
        (5)
) AS a1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM VALUES 
        (1, true)
        ,(2, false)
        --,(3, false)
        --,(4, true) /* we want to fail to match */
        --,(5, true) /* we want to fail to match again */
    v(id, PCT_COL_IND)
) AS b1 ON a1.id = b1.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM VALUES 
        --(1, true),
        --(2, true),
        --(3, false)
        (4, true),
        (5, false)
    v(id, PCT_COL_IND)
) AS final ON a1.id = final.id
WHERE final.id is NULL
    --OR nvl(a1.id,'0') <> nvl(final.id,'0' )
    OR nvl( b1.PCT_COL_IND,'0') <> nvl(final.PCT_COL_IND,'0')
;
```

| ID | PCT_COL_IND | DML_TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TRUE | I |
| 2 | FALSE | I |
| 3 | NULL | I |
| 4 | NULL | U |

so row 5 is not present because final.PCT_COL_IND is false, and the null of b1.PCT_COL_IND is replace with the text string "0" which implicitly is converted to a false boolean value, thus the row is dropped. Here we are starting to see the impact of using strings verse boolean's perhaps you want strings after all.

but row 4 is present because the final.pct_col_ind is true, which is different to the empty string

rows 1,2,3 are present because they are not in final, but "did not have results in b1" thus 3 is null.

BUT you b1 is from the same data as a1, so that case should not happen. But that is how I triggered case 4.. so now I am perplexed. I might have to think this over more..

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Kindly guide me with a solution. Thanks again :)